# What would be the process for applying interpolation in an hexbin diagram in matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, interpolation

I want to get the next **hexbin** diagram:

[image]

that was obtained from

```
np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=(30,30),density=True)
```

Into something like:

[image]

That was obtained with:

`plt.imshow(img,origin='bottom',cmap='magma',interpolation='bilinear')`

where `img`  is a **Numpy** array with dimensions `img.shape=(m,n)` that looks like:
[image]

would it make **any** difference?

Comment: Not really sure what your question/issue is

Comment: The interpolation techniques are based in a rectangular grid, I wonder if there is a way of doing this for hexagonal grids.